# in titanium alloy how to select row from picker

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

i have edit profile page with gender picker that have two picker rows (as one should expect...) male and female. i want to change the selected row according to data that i load from an API.
this is my view.xml

```
<Picker id="genderPicker">
    <PickerRow title="Male"></PickerRow>
    <PickerRow title="Female"></PickerRow>
</Picker>
```

style.tss

```
"Picker": {
      top: 2,
      bottom: 2,
      left: 110,
      width: 120,
      height: 50,
      backgroundColor: '#666',
      selectionIndicator: true
    }

    "PickerRow": {
      color: '#fff'
    }
```

controller.js

```
    if (gender == 'm') {
        Ti.API.info('g-m');
        $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 0, false);
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('g-f');
        $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 1, false);
    }
```

i get the value of the gender and according to it i set the selected row but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index of row is 0 not 1

```
 if (gender == 'm') {
    Ti.API.info('g-m');
    $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 0, false);
} else {
    Ti.API.info('g-f');
    $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 1, false);
}
```

Comment: you code work, you probably execute this code ou your "gender" is "m"
try to force change on your controller.js
$.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 1, false);

Answer (score 0):

Your controller.js should be

```
 if (gender == 'm') {
    Ti.API.info('g-m');
    $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 0, false);
 } else {
    Ti.API.info('g-f');
    $.genderPicker.setSelectedRow(1, 0, false);
 }
```

first param is the Column.
Send is the Row.